# Batch renaming files

Tags: shell, bash, rename

I have a directory full of images:

```
image0001.png
image0002.png
image0003.png
...
```

And I would like a one-liner to rename them to (say).

```
0001.png
0002.png
0003.png
...
```

How do I do this?

Comment: This is one of the top Unix command line FAQs, and I can't find it on this site already, so should we make this Community Wiki?

Comment: I don't see why. It's a specific question with a verifiable answer.

Comment: If you're running X it doesn't get much easier than `thunar -B *.png` for thunar's bulk-rename gui tool.

Comment: @dotjoe Thunar is not common to all X-based desktop environments. It would be better to say, "If you're running Xfce, it doesn't..." or "If you've installed Thunar, it doesn't..."

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If you are using Bash or other POSIX-compatible shell:

```
for f in *.png; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f#image}"
done
```

Comment: This is one of the parameter substitution methods shown in Mendel Coopers Advanced Bash-scripting guide http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: @W_Whalley I strongly recommend *avoiding* that guide, in favor of the [Wooledge Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Comment: @Wildcard: what are your reasons for recommending to avoid the ABS guide?

Comment: @ChristianSeverin promotion of bad practices and outright broken code.  Check links on my profile page.

Comment: If you don't know how to adapt this example for different file patterns, you might want to have a look at the [Parameter Expansion Section](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) of the guide mentioned above.

Comment: What is the meaning of `--` in `mv -- ` ?

Comment: @Wolf It causes contents of variables not get mistakenly used as arguments. Many commands support similar syntax.

Comment: I think changing `"${f#image}"` to `"${f/image/}"` is better because it covers cases when the pattern is not a prefix but a general substring

Comment: @Smar \*used as options, not arguments.

Answer (score 147):

On Debian and derivatives, [Perl's `rename` commandline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574) works similarly to `sed` like this:

```
  rename -v 's/image//' ./*.png
```

There's also the `rename` from `util-linux` that works like this, instead:

```
  rename -- image '' *.png
```

Comment: you really should explain that this is a perl programm that might have to be installed and that it takes regular expressions as the argument.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of that. I'll give credit to the canonical answer, when I identify it :)

Comment: This `rename` program came from a Perl examples distribution. Debian and Ubuntu ship it as `/usr/bin/rename`. Other Unix variants may not provide it, or may provide a completely different `/usr/bin/rename`.

Comment: On some systems it may be called `prename`. There is also more than one version of it, regardless of how it's named.

Comment: Some versions of `rename` take a _from_ _to_ replacement pattern: `rename [options] <expression> <replacement> <file>...`

Comment: If you are using a Debian based system then sudo apt-get install rename, then you can use the rename command. It is sed for filenames.

Comment: I wrote a script using perls rename and only now realised that it is SUPER SLOW. It can't even process 10 files in a second, which is really annoying if you work with thousands of files...

Comment: Thank you!  I was thinking I was using Perl's rename, and it wasn't working!  I guess I was using util-linux.  3 hours I tried to debug this!

Comment: I use `lubuntu` and have `rename.ul` [pre-installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444503/72988).

Comment: FYI for the version of `rename` that installs with `apt install rename` in ubuntu, the `-e` flag must be used in place of `-v`: `rename -e 's/image//' ./*.png`

Answer (score 68):

The zsh shell has a powerful batch rename command called `zmv`.

First you need to enable the `zmv` command as follows (this can go into your `~/.zshrc`).

```
autoload zmv
```

The basic syntax is `zmv PATTERN REPLACEMENT`. The pattern is a shell glob expression. Parts of the pattern can be surrounded by parentheses. The replacement text can contain `$1`, `$2`, etc. to refer to the Nth parenthesised group in the pattern. For example:

```
zmv 'image(*.png)' '$1'
```

You can also ask zsh to automatically define `$1`, `$2`, etc. to match the wildcard characters in the pattern:

```
zmv -w 'image*.png' '$1.png'
```

Comment: Really cool, as pointed in zmv's man this can be further simplified by adding alias mmv='noglob zmv -W' to:  mmv \*.c.orig orig/\*.c

Comment: Enabling `zmv` prezto requires uncommenting the line in your ~/.zpreztorc following `# Set the Zsh functions to load (man zshcontrib).` giving `zstyle ':prezto:load' zfunction 'zargs' 'zmv'`

Comment: For those who, (like me) rarely need to rename files, you don't _need_ to put `autoload zmv` in your `~/.zshrc`: you can also just run it whenever you need `zmv`.

Answer (score 52):

I normally use the nice and simple **mmv** ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/mmv.1.html)) utility for this usecase:

```
$ mmv "image*.png" "#1.png"
```

will perform your task.

The `#1` in the target pattern will be substituted with whatever matches the wildcard in the source pattern. This also works for several wildcards and can be used for example to change the order of parts of filenames. You can also easily do more complicated things like converting lower case to upper case letters.

Make sure to protect the patterns from the shell by quoting.

Answer (score 13):

### POSIX sh for loop

*Uses sed to rename*

```
for i in image*.png
do 
  mv -i -- "$i" "$(printf '%s\n' "$i" | sed '1s/^image//')"
done
```

Answer (score 13):

## qmv

The command `qmv` from `renameutils` opens an editor showing a list of filenames with two colums, separated by a tab. Each row shows one of the filenames, the same in both columns.  The right column is representing the new names of the files.
To make changes, edit the names on the right side.  In this example, `:%s/...` or visual block mode are helpful.

### Filenames in your editor

```
$ qmv *.png
```

In editor:

```
image0001.png           image0001.png
image0002.png           image0002.png
image0003.png           image0003.png         
~                                             
~                                             
~                                             
~                                             
"/tmp/user/1000/qmvxWyVMs" 3L, 93C
```

Edit names in right column:
(Removing the `image` prefix from all lines using visual block mode)

```
image0001.png           0001.png
image0002.png           0002.png
image0003.png           0003.png         
~                                             
~                                             
~                                             
~                                             
:wq
```

Log of renaming:

```
image0001.png -> 0001.png
image0002.png -> 0002.png
image0003.png -> 0003.png
```

---

(e.g. Ubuntu: `apt-get install renameutils`)

Answer (score 5):

I like Perl so:

```
perl -nlE '$old=$_; s/image//; qx(mv $old $_)'
```

You can also use the same pattern for other tasks like copying the files to another directory:

```
perl -nlE '$old=$_; s(image)(/path/to/new/dir/); qx(mv $old $_)'
```

Comment: Or (safer!): `rename($old,$_)`

Comment: Yes, calling sh and mv for every file is both inefficient and very dangerous. That code is basically a command injection vulnerability. The list of files would also need to be supplied somehow on perl's stdin, but as it's expected newline-delimited it can't take arbitrary file names.

Answer (score 3):

### recursive

*easy recurse selecting image*png files, and assumes no need to deal with newline, backslash in file names*

```
find . -name "image*.png" | while read f; do mv -v "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed -e 's/image//' - )"; done
```

Comment: Your solution here can't deal with newlines. It also depends on `echo` not modifying data, which it could do if it contains backslashes under some circumstances.

Comment: @Kusalananda - Thank you, I have removed incorrect 2nd answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using a shells that supports brace expansion ([Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion), Zsh, Ksh93, Fish, Csh, Tcsh):

```
for N in {0001..1000}; do mv "{image,}$N.png"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

### POSIX sh using a while loop

*Reading names from `find` command.*

```
find . ! -path . -prune -type f -name 'image*png' |
while IFS= read -r f; do
  mv "$f" "$(printf '%s\n' "$f" | sed -e 's/^\.\/image//' - )"
done
```

*Reading names from a file*

```
while IFS= read -r f; do
  mv "$f" "$(printf '%s\n' "$f" | sed -e 's/^\.\/image//' - )"
done < flist
```

Both of these approaches assume pathnames have no embedded newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Try brename (https://github.com/shenwei356/brename), a practical cross-platform command-line tool for safely batch renaming files/directories via regular expression (supporting Windows, Linux and OS X) .

[@patrickDurusau](https://twitter.com/patrickDurusau) said:

> Linux has a variety of batch file renaming options but I didn’t see any short-comings in brename that jumped out at me.

Features:

- **Cross-platform**. Supporting Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.
- **Safe**. By ***checking potential conflicts and errors***.
- **File filtering**. Supporting including and excluding files via regular expression.
  No need to run commands like `find ./ -name "*.html" -exec CMD`.
- **Renaming submatch with corresponding value via key-value file**.
- **Renaming via ascending integer**.
- **Recursively renaming both files and directories**.
- **Supporting dry run**.
- **Colorful output**.

Command:

```
$ brename -f .png -p image
[INFO] checking: [ ok ] 'image0001.png' -> '0001.png'
[INFO] checking: [ ok ] 'image0002.png' -> '0002.png'
[INFO] checking: [ ok ] 'image0003.png' -> '0003.png'
[INFO] 3 path(s) to be renamed
[INFO] renamed: 'image0001.png' -> '0001.png'
[INFO] renamed: 'image0002.png' -> '0002.png'
[INFO] renamed: 'image0003.png' -> '0003.png'
[INFO] 3 path(s) renamed
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Windows and linux**, this [Perl script](https://github.com/circulosmeos/rnm) will do; in this case:

```
$ rnm -l 's/^image//' '*.png'
```

The script could **run recursively under directories** and even prepending a count to all of them:

```
$ rnm -r 's/^/$counter./' '/\.png$/'
```

UTF-8 chars are also correctly treated, both in Windows and linux.

Comment: `rnm` was already suggested in 2015 in [a separate answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236425).

Comment: That's curious: I didn't know about that tool, it's different from the one proposed here: this one has no dependencies, no compilation, and runs on Windows and Linux. Also, I give an example on how to prepend a counter which the other example lacks (I think that other one could do that also but the documentation is fairly big)

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, no one mentioned [this well covered approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19384307/4175647):

```
find . | grep \.png$ | sed 'p;s/image//' | xargs -n2 mv
```

And if you like playing around with arguments:

```
find . | grep \.png$ | sed "p;s/image//" | xargs -n2 sh -c 'echo $1 $2' $0
```

Single quotes after `sh -c` matter

Comment: Quite a few issues: (1) filenames can be made of several lines so can't be processed line-wise (2) you're not quoting that backslash or `$`. Should be `grep '\.png$'`. (3) `s/image//` removes the first image in the path, so for a `./my-images/image0001.png` that would try and do `mv ./my-images/image0001.png ./my-s/image0001.png` and fail. You'd want to process the list depth first and only do the rename on the basename.

Comment: (continued) (4) xargs expects the words on input in a very specific format, which sed is not providing here. For instance, if the file paths contain quotes or blanks or backslash, that will fail. (5), echo can't be used for arbitrary data. (6), there are missing quotes around the `$0`, `$1`,`$2`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas feel free to edit my answer if you are willing to; my answer does not cover all the depth-in and many other things, it directly answers the question about one directory containing batch of images; from my perspective this rather simple solution

Comment: Because of the missing quotes, this `\.` doesn’t do what you think it does: `echo \.` prints `.`, without the backslash. Also, why waste resources piping `find` into `grep` when you can use `-name`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool: [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm) ([web page](http://neurobin.github.io/rnm/))

For your case the command would be:

```
rnm -rs '/^image//' *.png
```

You can find more examples/docs [here](http://neurobin.github.io/Docs/Linux/rnm/bulk-rename-in-linux/).