# Batch copying/moving files in unix?

Tags: command-line, rename, cp

Is there a way to batch copy/move files in unix? I thought it might be an option for `cp/mv` but I can't find any way to do it.

Comment: `cp` and `mv` are pretty good choices. What additional features do you need? For renaming, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1136/8250

Comment: Yes there is. What files are you going to copy/move?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "batch copy" that you couldn't get done by `cp` or `mv`?

Comment: @Lekensteyn and Mat: I'm trying to move every file in a directory I extracted from an archive into the directory aforementioned directory is contained in.

Answer (score 5):

`cp` and `mv` are both good tools for copying files and moving files respectively. Combined with shell constructs (loops like `for file in *; do ...; done`) or `find`, they become even more powerful.

If I understood your purpose correctly, you have extracted files like:

```
somedir/file.png
somedir/file.txt
```

and want to move all files into the parent directory such that it looks like:

```
file.png
file.txt
```

Using shell wildcards, assuming that you are in the directory `somedir`, you can use:

```
mv * ../
```

`*` is a glob pattern that expands to all files in the current directory. If you have hidden files (files and directories with a leading `.` in their filename), use `shopt -s dotglob` in `bash`).

I've mentioned `find` before. If you have a tree of files like:

```
somedir/000.txt
somedir/a/001.txt
somedir/a/004.txt
somedir/b/003.txt
somedir/b/002.txt
somedir/whatever/somethingunique.txt
```

and want to move all files in one directory (say, `seconddir`), use:

```
find -exec mv {} seconddir/ \;
```

This assumes that all filenames are unique, otherwise files would get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You might get away nicely with [rename](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html) as it's more apt to batch processing.