# batch rename a few files

Tags: shell-script, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch renaming files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files)

I have some files that I wish to rename in a single command. The files are names [thus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MymJZ.png). I want the E S Posthumus bit removed from the names and also the 01, 02 ...etc at the start of each file. How do I remove that?

Comment: Please copy and paste text instead of posting links to screenshots.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to strip off filename prefixes using just `bash`. Note that the **resulting filenames may collide** e.g if you have two files with the same song title. Hence the `-i` switch:

```
for f in *.mp3; do mv -i "$f" "${f#*Posthumus - }"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
rename 's/\d\d\s-\s[ .A-Za-z]+-\s//' *.mp3
01 - E.S. Posthumus - Ashielf Pi.mp3 renamed as Ashielf Pi.mp3
02 - E.S. Posthumus - Oraanu Pi.mp3 renamed as Oraanu Pi.mp3
```

*Edit:* If for some reason you don't have a version of `rename` installed which does the job, you can easily write the minimal version of the script yourself in Perl, and run that. This is from the [Unix FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part2/section-6.html), and works with the regex I provided above:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    #
    # rename script examples from lwall:
    #       rename 's/\.orig$//' *.orig
    #       rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/ unless /^Make/' *
    #       rename '$_ .= ".bad"' *.f
    #       rename 'print "$_: "; s/foo/bar/ if <stdin> =~ /^y/i' *

    $op = shift;
    for (@ARGV) {
        $was = $_;
        eval $op;
        die $@ if $@;
        rename($was,$_) unless $was eq $_;
    }
```

Comment: The problem with `rename` is multiple versions of it exist in the wild.  Always double check and use your local version's documentation to avoid mishaps.

Comment: @jw013 - really? That's interesting. How do they differ? My understanding was that `rename` is just a Perl script, accepting standard Perl regex.

Comment: I've never done a `rename` survey.  Not all implementation are Perl scripts however.  Just know that you should always check what syntax your `rename` supports before using it.

Comment: @ire_and_curses - a good example is debian. `/usr/bin/rename` is a symlink that is managed by the alternatives system. Two different servers with the same OS/distro and version may not have the same `/usr/bin/rename`.

Comment: @ire_and_curses Here is a manpage for the other rename: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename - it comes from util-linux.

Comment: Very interesting! I've updated my answer with a generic Perl script which will do the rename, if for some reason `/usr/bin/prename` isn't available.