# Bash Globbing Variable Substitution?

Tags: bash, shell, rename, wildcards, variable-substitution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch renaming files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files)

I want to rename files using their existing name as a base for the new one.

So if I can `ls` these files with

```
ls blue*+(.png)
```

I'd want to rename them something like

```
mv blue$(*)+(.png) $(1).png
```

except that doesn't work obviously. Is there syntax for these kind of variables in bash globbing or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The portable way to do this is

```
for f in blue*.png; do mv -- "$f" "${f#blue}"; done
```

All this requires is `mv` and works in not just `bash` but also any POSIX compatible shell which supports [standard POSIX parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).  No need for your system to have `zsh` or a particular version of `rename` installed.

Comment: can you talk me through the mv part of this command? thanks

Comment: @user1561108 The `${f#blue}` part removes the `blue` prefix from the beginning of `$f`.  See the link I added in the edit for more details.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian and derivatives (including Ubuntu), there's a rename command which can do what you want:

```
rename -n "s/\+\.png/.png/" blue*+.png
```

Remove the -n flag after testing to actualy apply the rename.

This `rename` command is a Perl script, not to be confused with the `rename` command from the util-linux suite. Other distributions may provide it as `prename` or `rename.pl` or not at all.

Answer (score 0):

With bash:

```
zsh -c '
  autoload -U zmv
  zmv "blue(*).png" "\$1.png"'
```

;-). Or more seriously, you'll find that zsh's zmv is a very powerful tool for all sorts of renaming jobs. Contrary to scripts you may come up with, that tool (or any other tool dedicated for the task like mmv or rename) takes extra care not to clobber files and is more likely to be more robust in corner cases.

Comment: title says Bash?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any easy way to do this in bash, but of course you can break the problem into several steps like cutting the prefix, remembering the extension and then replacing the several instances of the extension with single one.

```
for file in blue*+(.png); do tmp="${file#blue}"; extension="${file##*.}"; echo "$file" "${tmp/%+(.$extension)/}.$extension";done
```

if you are happy with the results, just type...

```
^echo^mv
```

and all the magic will happen. :)