# Renaming Files according to Pattern

Tags: bash, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch renaming files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files)

Let us assume that I have six files named:

```
1.a, 1.b, 1.c
2.a, 2.b, 2.c
```

where a,b,c are file extensions like sh, txt etc.

Now, I want to rename the files `1.a, 1.b, 1.c` with say `5.a, 5.b, 5.c` and `2.a, 2.b, 2.c` with `6.a, 6.b and 6.c`. Here both `2` and `6` are user supplied inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tried, but should work

```
$ rename 's/1/5/' 1.*
$ rename 's/2/6/' 2.*
```

[rename man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rename)

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
#!/bin/bash

for num in 1 2
do
    read -p "Enter new val for files starting with $num :" val
    for i in ${num}*.[abc]
    do
            ext=${i##*.}
            mv $i "$val.$ext"
    done
done
```

Comment: You can use `read -p` to combine the `read` and the prompt in the same command.

Comment: @jordanm : thanks for your input, updated the solution

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash function that will do the trick:

```
do_rename() {
   oldnum=$1 # assign parameters for clarity
   newnum=$2

   for f in "$oldnum".*; do # get all files matching the old number
       mv "$f" "$newnum"."${foo##*.}" # use a parameter expansion to get the exetension of the current filename
   done
}
```