# Batch renaming of files

Tags: shell, command-line, rename

I have a directory full of images:

```
DSCN4749.JPG
DSCN4750.JPG
DSCN4892.JPG
...
```

And I would like a one-liner to rename them to (say).

```
dscn4749.jpg
dscn4750.jpg
dscn4892.jpg
...
```

How do I do this?

Alternatives/extenstions/caveats

- I want to recurse
- The directory contains a mix of file types I only want to rename DSCN*.JPG files.
- bash solution
- perl solution
- zsh solution
- I want a new directory tree with hard links existing files.
- I want to change name more than just a case change eg dscn5555.JPG to 05555.jpg

...

Comment: This is intended to be a canonical Q&A on this subject (see this [meta discussion](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/lets-compile-a-list-of-canonical-qas?cb=1) ), please feel free to edit my answer to improve it but if you solution is different then add your own below Stating extension/caveat/alternative method

Comment: Most of these (all?) are already present here: [Batch renaming files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1136)

Comment: -1 it would be better to edit the question terdon linked to than to re-ask it.

Comment: @virtualxtc: Why is editing an ancient question better? Shouldn't the new question be formulated to ask about what has not been covered in the linked question?

Comment: @krlmlr I wish I could find the meta thread on this for you as I'm sure I won't be as clear as it was: **Whenever possible, you want to edit questions and answers so that this site has the best ones possible.**  However, if your edit would significantly change the intent of the question, then it is preferable to reference the original question (which also wasn't done) and ask a new one.

Answer (score 10):

With perl rename

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

Comment: Not worked for Me. I am in Linux Bash shell.

Answer (score 7):

### POSIX sh for loop

```
for i in ./DSCN*JPG; do mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | tr A-Z a-z)" ; done
```

### bash while loop

*good for unlimited number of files, reading a list of names from a file*

Reading names from `find` command.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'DSCN*JPG' | while IFS= read -r f; do
  mv -v "$f" "$( tr A-Z a-z <<< $f )"
done
```

Reading list of names in a file named flist

```
while IFS= read -r f; do mv -v "$f" "$( tr A-Z a-z <<<$f )"; done < flist
```

Comment: This is intended to be a canonical Q&A on this subject (see this [meta discussion](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/lets-compile-a-list-of-canonical-qas?cb=1) ), please feel free to edit my answer to improve it but if you solution is different then  add your own below Stating  extension/caveat/alternative method

Comment: Why is the for loop good for only a limited number of files (esp. since a for loop doesn't suffer from a MAX_ARGS limitation)?

Comment: Also, the while loop solution suffers from potential bugs when the listed files contain whitespace or start with a dash.

Comment: @kijiro My mistake re for loop comment, will remove tks.

Answer (score 5):

Some linux distributions have a program called "mmv" (e.g. [debian](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/mmv)).  This can perform a rename based on pattern matching of filenames.  In your case, the command you'd want is:

```
mmv 'DSCN*.JPG' 'dscn#1.jpg'
```

It interprets the filename pattern itself, rather than relying on shell expansion, so remember to quote the wildcards.  In the destination pattern, `#1` refers to the first wildcard in the source pattern and so on.  I'd suggest running

```
mmv -n 'DSCN*.JPG' 'dscn#1.jpg'
```

first, which will give a list of operations that will be performed as a dry run.

It can also handle recursively renaming, using the special `;` pattern (which matches any number of subdirectory levels, similarly to the `**` pattern used by some other tools).  So to perform this operation recursively, the command is:

```
mmv ';DSCN*.jpg' '#1dscn#2.jpg'
```

It can also handle case transformation of the filenames itself, so if you weren't sure that all your files started with the DSCN prefix, for example, the following would work:

```
mmv '*.JPG' '#l1.jpg'
```

or even

```
mmv '*' '#l1'
```

or

```
mmv ';*' '#1#l2'
```

to perform the rename recursively.

A new directory tree with hard links to the original files can be produced using the `-l` option:

```
mmv -l ';DSCN*.JPG' '../output/#1dscn#2.jpg'
```

I haven't tested this, but I believe it will create directories as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

### recursive

*easy recurse selecting DSCN*JPG files, and assumes no need to deal with newline in file names*

```
find . -name "DSCN*.JPG" | while read f; do mv -v "$f" "$( tr A-Z a-z <<<$f )"; done
```

*Safe, can deal with spaces, new lines, backslashes and anything else*:

```
find . -name "DSCN*.JPG" | while IFS= read -r f; do 
   mv -v "$f" "$( tr A-Z a-z <<<$f )"; 
done
```

Answer (score 2):

### zsh

First load the `zmv` builtin with:

```
% autoload -U zmv
```

This can be run from the command line or put in `.zshrc` to always be enabled.  To rename all of your files to lowercase, you simply use the command:

```
% zmv '*.JPG' '${(L)f}'
```

This will rename all files matching `*.JPG` to the same name but lowercase.  This is one of the simplest use cases of `zmv` and it can do much more powerful batch renaming.

Answer (score 1):

### change name with sed

*for more complicated name changes*/

```
find . -name DSCN\*.JPG | while read f; do 
   mv -v "$f" "$( sed -e 's/\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9]*\.\)\(JPG\)$/\2jpg/'  <<<$f )"; 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

### Generic pattern

As you can see from the answers, the generic pattern is

[Produce a set of file names to work on] | [read each name and run actionCommand]

actionCommand performs the desired action eg mv and generally takes two paramteres original file name and new file name.

#### producing filename

find is generally used.

To handle filenames with unusual characters the -print0 is used to terminate each string printed with the null character. However the reading sid of the pipe also needs to cooperate and read characters until null is read instead of terminating prematurely after a space.

#### reading each filename

Some commands can take a -0 option to handle the reading side of a null terminated character string.

The command `xargs` was designed for this purpose

bash has `read -d\0`

### actionCommand

A general form `cmd p1 p2` example `mv oldfilename newfilename`

### producing the new filename

The new filename is usually derived from the original filename.

It can be as simple as appending a string, eg `$oldname.New`

- `tr` is good for simple translation of characters
- `sed` power editing of filenames

#### bash command substition

Example `$( tr "{}" _ <<< $oldname )`

command output substitution `$( )`
command that is run `tr "{}" _` with input read from variable $oldname