# Replace occurrences of character in filenames

Tags: rename

How can I replace all the occurrences of the `+` character in all the filenames in the current working directory with the space character?

I know that there's the linux command `rename` but I'm not sure how I'd use it to do this.

**Example:**

Early+Christians -> Early Christians

Comment: There are many possible duplicates to this Q: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153470/rename-files-with-rename-command & http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114414/batch-renaming-of-files are just a few.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
rename -n 'y/+/ /' *
```

`y` is used for translating characters from one set to another. Consider the example from [`man rename`](http://man.he.net/man1/rename):

```
To translate uppercase names to lower, you'd use
       rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

The `-n` is used for testing out  the expression. Once you're satisfied with the results, run `rename` without it to perform the actual renaming.

I should mention that the `rename` I am talking of is `perl-rename`, known as `prename` (and available as `rename`) on Debian-based Linux distros, the same command seen in [ntzrmtthihu777's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170963/70524).

Comment: @AvinashRaj for simple translations it's better to use `y` (or `tr`) over `s`: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=327021

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes. That's what `y` does. Try it: `perl -pe 'y/a/b/' <<<'aaaaaaaaaaa'`

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `mv` to rename files. Copy and paste this into terminal or turn it into a script:

```
for f in *; do
    # check if its a file
    if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
        new_name=$(echo "$f" | sed 's/+/ /g')
        # replace this echo with mv
        echo "$f" "$new_name"
    fi
done
```

Replace the second `echo` with `mv` if you are satisfied with the results. As it will rename all the files in the directory that loop is run in.

Comment: I think you're escaping the wrong character there (`\ ` instead of `\+`).

Comment: @muru thanks for bringing that up. I just ran it again and it seems that escaping the characters isn't necessary. It runs the same in single and double quotes, escaped or not.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I love using perl-rename for such tasks. For instance, I'd use
`perl-rename 's:_: :g' file_name_here` to change all underscores to spaces, resulting in `file name here`. You can think of it as a sed rename thing :)