# bash replace part of string based on location

Tags: bash, sed

I've looked around for a one line solution ( as bash offers ) to replace part of filename.

Given that a folder has image sequence like

```
ve2_sq021_sc001_v000.0101.jpg
ve2_sq021_sc001_v000.0102.jpg
ve2_sq021_sc001_v000.0103.jpg
ve2_sq021_sc001_v000.0104.jpg
```

Need to replace only v000 with v09 ( say ). How is it possible (throughout directory).

Comment: while if i know that it is v000 in fourth position then i can do as suggested. My question is - How is it possible to go to fourth location after _ and replace that with "v09". Can regular expression come useful here.

Comment: It's a duplicate of [Batch renaming files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1136/22222)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the unix command `rename` installed you can do this trivially like this:

```
$ rename v000 v09 *.jpg

$ ls -1
ve2_sq021_sc001_v09.0101.jpg
ve2_sq021_sc001_v09.0102.jpg
ve2_sq021_sc001_v09.0103.jpg
ve2_sq021_sc001_v09.0104.jpg
```

**NOTE:** This is using the `rename` implementation that's included with the package [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux).

Comment: This is a useful command. You could merge it into @terdon's answer above.

Comment: ok. This may be silly to ask. how will replace in a path in script.
pth="/tmp/images"
rename v000 v09 $pth/*.jpg
this does not work. Error is "No such file or directory"

Comment: @nish - there are 2 different implementations of `rename`. Which distro is this?

Comment: CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

Comment: @nish - OK so the example I showed you will work then, that's the CentOS/Fedora version as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in $(ls ve2*); do mv $f $(echo $f | sed s/v000/v09/g ); done
```

If you want to make it recursive, you could use find instead of ls ve2*

Comment: **Do not ever** parse the output of `ls`. You'll be sorry for it the instant you encounter a filename or path containing whitespace. Instead, use the globbing of you shell (`for f in ve2*; do`) or `find`'s `-exec` parameter.

Comment: Also, there's no need to spawn a `sed` instance for each file to be renamed. Either [use `rename`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114693/28235) or at least let `bash` handle the strong replacement: `${f//v000/v09}` evaluates to the value of `f` with all occurrences of 'v000' replaced by 'v09'.