# Batch renaming series episodes from 1x01* to S01E01* pattern

Tags: bash, rename

Bash: How do I batch rename series episodes from `1x01*` to `S01E01*` pattern?

I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1139/126755), but I am rather lost in how to modify it to my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch renaming files](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash substrings will do:

```
for i in ?x??*
do
  mv "$i" "S0${i:0:1}E${i:2:2}${i:4}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach, using the `rename` command.  Drop the `-n` when happy with proposed renames.

Explanation:

- `s/` = substitute
- `(\d+)` = match 1 or more digits (season)
- `x` = match the "x" character
- `(\d+)` = match 1 or more digits (episode)
- `/`  = end of search string, start of substitute string
- `S0` = insert text "S0"
- `$1` = insert the first matched digits from earlier (season)
- `E` = insert the "E" character
- `$2` = insert the second matched digits from earlier (episode)
- `/` = end of substitute string

-

```
rename -n -e 's/(\d+)x(\d+)/S0$1E$2/' *
rename(Breaking_Bad_1x01.mkv, Breaking_Bad_S01E01.mkv)
rename(Shameless_3x05.mp4, Shameless_S03E05.mp4)
```

Answer (score -3):

You may do it one by one:

```
for f in 1x01*; do
    n=`echo $f | sed 's/^1x01/S01E01/'`
    mv $f $n
done
```

Comment: This only handles the one episode, not other files named by a similar pattern.

Comment: You want to change `1x` to `S01E`, so `for f in 1x* ; do echo mv "$f" "${f/1x/S01E}" ; done` check that it looks OK, then remove the echo.