# How to rename files with different extensions

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line, osx, rename

Say I have these files:

```
essay.aux                   essay.out
essay.dvi                   essay.pdf
essay.fdb_latexmk           essay.tex
essay.fls                   essay.toc
essay.log                   ......
```

How do I rename them to:

```
new_name.aux                new_name.out
new_name.dvi                new_name.pdf
new_name.fdb_latexmk        new_name.tex
new_name.fls                new_name.toc
new_name.log                ......
```

The problem is that they have different extensions rather than different names, so I cannot use answers from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1136/158931). Also, I'm on macOS which doesn't have a `rename` command.

Comment: I believe you were downvoted because you have not shown any evidence of an attempt.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Jesse_b It's dangerous for a rookie to execute *anything* from the command line, right? I really don't want to risk losing my files. But since you've asked, I'll make a new directory and `touch` some random files and do some experiments ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote the question btw but yes that is an excellent idea.

Comment: Macs have `perl`, so the easiest way to do this is to install the [File::Rename](https://metacpan.org/release/File-Rename) CPAN module, then you can use the `rename` script which is included as an example.  It's the same perl rename script mentioned in many answers to similar questions on this site.  It's more work up-front, but then you have the best file-renaming tool available for all future renaming tasks.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/a/345527/4877  - in short, if you have `brew` already installed - and you should - just run `brew install rename`.  This is **not** the same as the `File::Rename` script but was inspired by it. It seems to have many more command-line options, but is backwards compatible with the `rename` referenced here so frequently.

Comment: @Kusalananda I’m done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution I was able to get working:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob

my_files='/root/temp/files'
old_name='essay'
new_name='new_name'

for file in "${my_files}/${old_name}"*; do
    my_extension="${file##*.}"
    mv "$file" "${my_files}/${new_name}.${my_extension}"
done
```

- `shopt -s nullglob`

This will prevent an error if the directory it's parsing is empty

- `for file in "${my_files}/${old_name}"*; do`

We are going to loop over every `file` in `/root/temp/files/` so long as it begins with `essay`

- `my_extension="${file##*.}"`

This will greedily trim anything up to the **last** `.` found in the filename (hopefully leaving you with only the extension)

- `mv "$file" "${my_files}/${new_name}.${my_extension}"`

This moves the old file to the new filename while reserving the extension. (rename)

Comment: If you `cd` to that directory, you can change the names in one step (in bash at least) with `${file/#old/new}` i.e. `mv "$file" "${file/#old/new}"`

Comment: @WillCrawford Please write up an answer, that is much better than my solution.

Comment: It's just a change to the line in your loop, it still needs the `for file in ... ; do ... ; done` around it.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use find:

```
 find . -name "essay.*" -exec sh -c 'mv $1 new_name.${1##*.}' rename {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using zsh, you could do this:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -w 'essay.*' 'new_name.$1'
```

courtesy of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1141/158931).

Answer (score 1):

I Have used below command to get the output

First i have used for loop in `for` loop i have mentioned all the  file extensions then in loop i have used `awk` command to rename the file as per requirements.

Tested and worked fine

command

```
for i in aux out dvi pdf fdb_latexmk tex fls toc; do  find . -type f -iname "*.$i"| awk -F "./" '{print $2}' | awk -F "." '{print "mv" " " $1"."$2 " " "new_name."$2}'| sh; done
```