# Why /usr/bin/rename.ul has an extension?

Tags: filenames, command, executable

I found a command `rename.ul` on my Ubuntu machine.  It comes from `util-linux` package.

It is odd for me because I rarely see executables with extension.  In addition, it seems unnecessary because the file is compiled.

Are there any historical or technical reasons on it?

I'm also confused because I could not find file format associated this extension.

Comment: I’d guess Util-Linux, based on http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/rename.ul.1.html

Comment: I see. I thought the extension indicates file type such as `.pl` for perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extension is to avoid conflict with the multitude of `rename` commands otherwise available on Debian. [This change](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/commit/539a6ea6866e9afe2247ddbba436c0538a515617) was made in 2007 in response to [Debian bug #439647](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=439647):

> /usr/bin/rename is managed by the alternatives system (with Perl's
>   version the default). util-linux 2.13~rc3-8 installs its own binary
>   there, instead of registering it as an alternative.

In response, the `util-linux` `rename` was renamed to be `rename.ul`.

Even so, `rename.ul` syntax is so far different from the Perl variants that it's not added to the alternatives system by default (see [Debian bug #439935](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=439935)).

Answer (score 5):

As the commenters have guessed, it is probably the [Debian Alternatives system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) in action.

If a distribution has multiple packages that contain an identically-named file, the creator of the package needs to know about it, and there needs to be a mechanism for the administrator to choose which one of them they want to use. So all the conflicting files get renamed (usually with suffixes, but this can be specified in the package metadata) and the original filename will become a symbolic link pointing to `/etc/alternatives/<original filename>`. That, in turn, will be another symbolic link pointing back to one of the now-renamed files.

The system administrator can use the `update-alternatives` tool to choose which version of the file will be pointed to by the original name. The other versions can still be reached using the new names.

The `update-alternatives` tool can handle "families" of things, so when e.g. you have both the traditional and OpenBSD netcat installed and use `sudo update-alternatives --config nc` to switch the default one way or another, the corresponding man page name will get switched too.

A common example would be `/usr/bin/editor`. On Debian-style systems, that's a symbolic link that other programs can use to get the "default text editor on this system, whatever it is". After a minimal installation, it is likely to default to `nano`, so `editor example.txt` will open the text file in `nano`, and `man editor` will show the man page of `nano`.

But if you install an editor that has a higher priority in the alternatives system, e.g. `joe`, then it automatically becomes the new default, so now `editor example.txt` will use `joe` instead, and `man editor` will also now show `joe`'s man page. You can also use `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` to choose which of the installed editors you want to be the default, and once you've made a choice this way, the automatic priorities won't override it.

Comment: Is it recommended to alias `rename` to `rename.ul` if I never install the `original rename`?

Comment: The alias seems not intelligent because: rename.ul syntax is so far different from the Perl variants.