# What is the bash code to remove varying characters in a file name up to a certain point?

Tags: regular-expression

I have a set of files that vary in characters. For Example:

```
IDNR19_15_037_S514_L001_R1_001.fastq
IDNR19_02_016_S238_L001_R1_001.fastq
```

I would like to remove all of the characters up the point of `S514` and `S238`, while keeping everything that comes after. Is this possible to do when the files have different numbers as shown in my example?

There are around 1,100 files, so doing this manually would be pretty time consuming.

The closest I have been able to do is:

```
rename 's/IDNR19_//g' *.fastq
```

to remove the IDNR19_ portion, but this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch renaming files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files)

Comment: In particular, the Perl-based `rename` command, if you can get it in whichever OS you're using

Comment: I have tried rename, but I cannot get it to work because of the variation in the file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these are names of files on disk that you want to rename, not strings stored in a variable or in a text file.  You may use a simple shell loop:

```bash
for name in *.fastq; do
    newname=${name#*_*_*_}
    printf 'Would move "%s" to "%s"\n' "$name" "$newname"
    # mv -i -- "$name" "$newname"
done
```

This loops over all names that matches the pattern `*.fastq` in the current directory (you may want to be more specific with this pattern by e.g. changing it to `IDNR*.fastq`).  For each filename, it constructs a new name by removing the prefix that matches the filename globbing pattern `*_*_*_`.  This is done using [a standard parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

For safety, the `mv` is commented out.  You should run the code once to see that it does the right thing before enabling the `mv`.

Using one of the various `rename` utilities (the one based on Perl's `File::Rename` module; there are a number of different ones, see "[What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename)"):

```
rename -n -v 's/.*?_.*?_.*?_//' -- *.fastq
```

or shorter,

```
rename -n -v 's/(.*?_){3}//' -- *.fastq
```

This more or less does the same thing as the shell code above, but using a Perl substitution.  The substitution removes the initial bits of the filename string by matching the three substrings between the underscores using a non-greedy `.*` match.   Remove the `-n` option when you are confident that it does the right thing.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much.