# Is it possible to use a repeated glob expression in a "synchronized" way within the same shell command?

Tags: bash, shell, mv

Sorry for the poor title. What I am trying to do is the following. I have a directory with (say) a 1000 files with names of the form `Foo_bar_1,...,Foo_bar_1000`. I would like to remove the 'bar' from each file name. For a single file this is easy, e.g.: `mv Foo_bar_1 Foo_1`.

Obviously I could process all files in this way using a loop. However, I am wondering if there is an easy way to do this without a loop using the `mv` command an regexps. I can match any source file with the expression `Foo_bar_*`. Is there any way I can now "access" the text that was matched with `*` ?

What I want to write is something like `mv Foo_bar_* Foo_*`, where the second `*` in the destination file should be equal to the string that was matched with `*` in the source file. How can this be done?

Comment: @pLumo If it can be done with a different command (or commands) without any loops, I'd be interested.

Comment: Also see [TLDP](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x4055.htm). [AskUbuntu has a related question.](https://askubuntu.com/q/1217683/11316) `mmv` for me is more natural to use, but YMMV.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcards are expanded by your shell **before** a command runs. So this will be executed:

```
mv Foo_bar_1 Foo_bar_2 ... Foo_bar_1000 Foo_bar_1 Foo_bar_2 ... Foo_bar_1000
```

or if you have files like `Foo_foo_1`, they will be added too as they match the second wildcard.

So no, it is not possible.

Also, `mv` does only accept a single target.

---

You can make a `for` loop:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f/_bar_/_}"; done
```

or use some batch rename tools for that:

Perl rename tool:

```
rename 's/_bar_/_/' *
```

"normal" rename tool:

```
rename '_bar_' '_' *
```

See also:

- [Batch renaming files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files)
- [What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229230/whats-with-all-the-renames-prename-rename-file-rename)

Comment: Thanks! Even though it could not be done with a single mv command, it was a very helpful answer. Also, thanks for the links.