# Procedurally renaming files in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, files, kubuntu

I have a bunch of files names topic1.pdf, topic2.pdf, ... which I want to rename to newName1.pdf, ... is there any way this can be done 'neatly' as in something like
`$ mv topic*.pdf newName*.pdf`?

Comment: @Panki That did the trick. [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1179/552492), specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a one-liner `for` loop (this assumes `bash` or similar)

```
for file in topic*.pdf; do mv "$file" "${file/topic/newName}"; done
```

If your shell can't do that substitution, you can use `sed` instead:

```
for file in topic*.pdf; do mv "$file" "$(printf "%s\n" "$file" | sed 's/topic/newname/')"; done
```