# Rename numbered files based on a list of corresponding names

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

I want to rename my files using a .txt file with proper names
These are my files:

```
lesson1.mp4
lesson2.mp4
lesson3.mp4
...
```

This is my txt file with names:

```
1 Entry to vim
2 Basics of vim
3 Vim motion
...
```

The result I want to have is:

```
1 Entry to vim.mp4
2 Basics of vim.mp4
3 Vim motion.mp4
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+rename+files+add+extension may help. There are many questions on unix.stackexchange.com that address renaming by pattern

Comment: Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files

Comment: Cross-post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74791172/rename-multiple-files-with-text-file-bash?noredirect=1#comment131994959_74791172

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, read the lines from the text file into an array, extract the number from each filename and subtract one so that you can use it as array index (`bash` starts at `0`) to select the corresponding element from the array:

```
readarray -t dest < names_list.txt
for f in lesson*.mp4; do i=${f:6:-4}; mv -- "$f" "${dest[i-1]}.mp4"; done
```

It's similar with `zsh`, only that indexing starts at `1` so no need to subtract one from the filename numbers:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
dest=( ${(f@)mapfile[names_list.txt]} )
for f in lesson*.mp4; do i=${f:6:-4}; mv -- "$f" "${dest[i]}.mp4"; done
```

Comment: +1, but `${dest[((i-1))]}` could be written as just `${dest[i-1]}` in the bash version.   From man bash, under the Arrays heading: **The subscript is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a number.**

Comment: @cas - thanks, that's also true for `zsh`... bad habits always hard to break...

Comment: Thank you so much!